# python: random letters from a given string

Tags: python

how can i take random letters from a given string in python..i've tried certain codes but all generated letters different from the string's.

Answer (score 11):

```
import random
random.choice('string')
# If you want more than 1 char, say n
''.join(random.sample('string',n))
```